# Why using default trash value for string is wrong?

Tags: java, c#, syntax, architecture

**tl;dr;**

Why using

```
string myVariable = "someInitialValueDifferentThanUserValue99999999999";
```

as default value is wrong?

**explanation of situation:**

I had a discussion with a colleague at my workplace.

He proposed to use some trash value as default in order to differentiate it from user value.
An easy example it would be like this:

```
string myVariable = "someInitialValueDifferentThanUserValue99999999999";
...
if(myVariable == "someInitialValueDifferentThanUserValue99999999999")
{
   ...
}
```

This is quite obvious and intuitive for me that this is wrong.
But I could not give a nice argument for this, beyond that:

- this is not professional.
- there is a slight chance that someone would input the same value.

Once I read that if you have such a situation your architecture or programming habits are wrong.

**edit:**
Thank you for the answers. I found a solution that satisfied me, so I share with the others:

It is good to make a bool guard value that indicates if the initialization of a specific object has been accomplished.

And based on this private bool variable I can deduce if I play with a string that is default empty value "" from my mechanism (that is during initialization) or empty value from the user.

For me, this is a more elegant way.

Comment: Details:
The situation is more complex because we use SDK and some embedded framework, and finally, we have some slot value that is working in (value, hasValue) manner. Where the value is the actual value and hasValue is a boolean that indicates if we have value at all. 
Something like manual nullable (we do not have nullables in framework perhaps).

Then we are a little limited with a constructor and set values methods for such tuples.

Because of this, we cannot use null as our default not initialized value and empty string as the user's empty input.

Comment: Would using `Optional<String>` be possible? Because that class was kind of introduces to handle those "Check if value is actually present" cases. Otherwise since you say "we cannot use null as our default" I don't see what else you could do but define a non-null value as your default.

Comment: As for why it is not a good idea: In my opinion this is mostly about writing understandable and maintainable code. Imagine someone else having to work with and change that code in the future. Would that person immediately  understand that this String variable has a special value that stands for "The value is not set" that he needs to handle in a special way? I somehow doubt that. When encountering an Optional however every java programmer should know that this means the value might not be there, that those cases need to be handled how he can check for that with the default isPresent()  method.

Comment: It seems like extra work to me.  Perhaps a better solution is to represent your value with a type (`Optional` might work for you, or the C# equivalent), this will allow the compiler to enforce correctness over if the value has been set by a user or no.  Chances are your problem is else where, for example allowing the user to provide an empty value in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Gavin and OH GO SPIDERS. You have shown me a nice mechanism, however I use C#. I used Java as tag, because I believe is more architectural concept or "clean-code". 
For understandable code there is possibility to write this default trash value as const string, so it is more mainatable and understandable (this actually was a proposition of my colleague at the end of discussion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small elaboration on "It's not professional":
It's often a bad idea, because

- it wastes memory when not a constant (at least in Java - of course, unless you're working with very limited space that's negligible).
- Even as constant it may introduce ambiguity once you have more classes, packages or projects ("Was it NO_INPUT, INPUT_NOT_PROVIDED, INPUT_NONE?")
- usually it's a sign that there will be no standardized scope-bound Defined_Marker_Character in the Project Documentation like suggested in the other answers
- it introduces ambiguity for how to deal with deciding if an input has been provided or not

In the end you will either have a lot of varying `NO_INPUT` constants in different classes or end up with a self-made `SthUtility` class that defines one constant `SthUtility.NO_INPUT` and a static method `boolean SthUtility.isInputEmpty(...)` that compares a given input against that constant, which basically is reinventing `Optional`. And you will be copy-pasting that one class into every of your projects.

Comment: That is answer I kind of expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### Optional

Optional can be used.

> Returns an empty Optional instance. No value is present for this Optional.
>
> API Note:
>
> Though it may be tempting to do so, avoid testing if an object is empty by comparing with == against instances returned by Option.empty(). There is no guarantee that it is a singleton. Instead, use isPresent().

Ref: [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty)

### Custom escape sequence shared by server and client

1. Define default value
2. When the user enter's the default value, escape the user value

### Use a marker character

1. Always define the first character as the marker character
2. Take decision based on this character and strip this character for any actual comparison
3. Define clear boundaries for the check as propagating this character across multiple abstractions can lead to code maintenance issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need as you can do the following as of `Java 11` which was four releases ago.

```
String value = "";
// true only if length == 0
if (value.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Value is empty");
}

String value = " ";
// true if empty or contains only white space
if (value.isBlank()) {
   System.out.println("Value is blank");
}
```

And I prefer to limit uses of such strings that can be searched in the class file that might possibly lead to exploitation of the code.